# How do I add multiple values to GRUB_CMDLINE_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub?

Tags: boot, networking, dual-boot, grub2, kernel

In order to turn the long interface naming system off so that interfaces go from `wlp2s0` and `wlx00c0ca828489` to `wlan0` and `wlan1`, you have to add `net.ifnames=0` into `/etc/default/grub`. There is already a value in this setting:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

**How would I go about adding multiple values to this?**

Could I add multiple values like this?:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash, net.ifnames=0"
```

Or like this?:

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash","net.ifnames=0"
```

Could I add `net.ifnames=0` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` like this?:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="net.ifnames=0"
```

But then this wouldn't be the default the value?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Kernel parameters in `/etc/default/grub`'s `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` variable are simply separated with just spaces:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash net.ifnames=0"
```

This sets the three parameters `quiet`, `splash` and `net.ifnames=0`.

Also, as correctly pointed out in the comments, don't forget to update your GRUB configuration with the changed parameters afterwards, by running:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: Thank you i didnt even know  `quiet` and `splash` where seperate parameters

Comment: No, but you must edit it with elevated privileges, e.g. using `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`.

Comment: Don't forget to say `update-grub` after you change the file.

Comment: @O.Jones You're right, I included your note. Thanks.