# Can I safely edit /boot/config* file?

Tags: boot, kernel, configuration, low-latency

On my Ubuntu 22.04.3 the full file name is `/boot/config-6.5.0-14-generic`. Can I safely edit `CONFIG_PREEMPT` and `CONFIG_HZ` entries in this file?

If yes, will setting:

```
CONFIG_PREEMPT=yes
CONFIG_HZ_1000=yes
```

turn it into the low latency version `linux-lowlatency-hwe-6.5`? Is there more "special sauce" in low latency kernel than these two settings? They are discussed in https://ubuntu.com/blog/industrial-embedded-systems-iii, but I couldn't find an answer to my question there.

Comment: You can edit them, but editing them won't do you any good. The kernel has already been built using that config; you'll need to rebuild it using `make oldconfig` (IIRC) from the corresponding kernel sources.

Comment: @muru So this is a read only file for a user who doesn't compile the kernel.

Comment: Yes, it's only informative.

Comment: what is wrong with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="threadirqs preempt=full tsc=reliable numa=on nosmt=force nohz=1-5 rcu_nocbs=1-5"`  ?

Comment: @Rinzwind I have to find out what it means, in order to answer your question.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/992049/how-do-i-add-multiple-values-to-grub-cmdline-default-in-etc-default-grub ;)